# Applying some features of a DF to another DF

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is a beginner question.
Let s assume we have 2 dataframes with the same index and the same columns but have different data.

How do I replace df1 data where df2 has np.nan, and replace them with np.nan

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.DataFrame(
                 [[1,3,np.nan],[5,3,np.nan],[np.nan,6,2]],
                 index=['a','b','c'],
                 columns=['01-10-1999','01-17-1999','01-24-1999']
                 )

df2=pd.DataFrame(
                 [[101,203,np.nan],[507,31,18],[12,np.nan,2]],
                 index=['a','b','c'],
                 columns=['01-10-1999','01-17-1999','01-24-1999']
                 )
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `mask`:

```
df1.mask(df2.isna())
```

Output:

```
   01-10-1999  01-17-1999  01-24-1999
a         1.0         3.0         NaN
b         5.0         3.0         NaN
c         NaN         NaN         2.0
```